# What is the limit of Matrix? Getting redirected to 404 error on entry with large number of Matrix rows

Tags: matrix, assets, pixelandtonic, memory-limit

The entry I'm having problems has a Matrix field with over 100 rows, on 8 columns of data (7 simple text fields, 1 dropdown with 2 options). When attempting to add just one more row and hitting the submit button, the server seems to be choking and coming up with a the default 404 page set for the website...no error messages or anything to tell what's actually going on. Checking the PHP error logs also shows nothing up.

I've attempted to up the 'memory_limit' to 2048M and the 'max_execution_time' to 300, but neither of these makes any difference.

Running EE v2.5.5 and Matrix v2.5.10, there's are also another Matrix field, and Assets field and a WYGWAM field on this entry.

A strange thing is that I can update this entry on my local MAMP setup, but not the Production server.

Comment: Is the session_save_path correct / working? I've had this exact same problem a couple of times with far less rows but setting max_execution_time as you have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you're bumping into some resource or config setting limit, you just have to figure out which one. A common culprit (other than memory_limit), is max_input_vars.

Comment: This particular server is running as a VPS using cPanel's WHM. Looking at it's PHP config editor, looks like I'm not able to edit that value specifically. If adding a php.ini file to the server directly for this domain, at what level to I put it, the /public_html/.. directory?

Comment: I believe if you put it there, it would apply to all (any) domains you have under there.

Comment: Weird thing is that it works locally, and the max_input_vars show the same value in PHP info for both local and production.

Comment: Try doing a phpinfo() on both and use a diff tool to see what the differences are.

Comment: Not sure my skills know what you're talking about at this level.

Comment: Created a file called phpinfo.php in your public_html.  Add this to it: <?php phpinfo(); Point your browser to domain.com/phpinfo.php.  Do that locally and on the server that has the issue and compare all of the values of each to find the differences.

Comment: OK, thanks Brad, top work. Will get to the bottom of this. Have received instructions from hosting provider on upping the max_input_vars too.

Comment: Redirecting to a 404 has mod_security written all over it, too. Check that with your host as well.

Comment: There was a column in the Matrix field that we didn't need (wasn't being utilised) so we removed it and that allowed us to get a few more rows into the field, but ended back at the some spot again. Arranged with hosting provider to increase the max_input_vars to '1500' and no longer have the problem. Thanks Brad for the input.